# recursive diff is extremely slow - checking contents of directories

Tags: bash, diff, rsync

I am running a diff on two directories, recursively, with a few options. The directories are somewhat large, however, I am trying to just see the differences in the contents of folders, not between the files, using the -q option (am i using this right?)

I have also tried rsync dry run, that seems to take equally as long. The output goes through sed, I have tried without, it doesn't seem to effect anything. I also ignore hidden files. I think I may be mis-using diff -q to just compare the contents of 2 directories.

I used a code block from another tip to time how long just comparing ONE of these directories was (1 directory, 14 subdirectories) and it took 88 minutes. However, every file was a 30 minutes long TV-show, so if diff is comparing these files, that makes sense, but I thought that -q would cause that to not happen?

Also, one directory is mounted over AFP, one is a firewire connected external drive. This doesn't matter, because I copied both directories locally and the diff took the same amount of time.

I have a solution to this - I ran ls -1 over both directories and diff'd the output - but why is diff taking so long to run?

Here is the code; any suggestions?

```
#!/bin/bash

before="$(date +%s)"

diff -r -x '.*' /Volumes/directory1/ /Volumes/directory2/ | sed 's/^.\{24\}//g' > /Volumes/stuff.txt
diff -r -x '.*' /Volumes/directory3/ /Volumes/directory4/ | sed 's/^.\{24\}//g' > /Volumes/stuff.txt
diff -r -x '.*' /Volumes/directory5/ /Volumes/directory6/ | sed 's/^.\{24\}//g' > /Volumes/stuff.txt
diff -r -x '.*' /Volumes/directory7/ /Volumes/directory8/ | sed 's/^.\{24\}//g' > /Volumes/stuff.txt
diff -r -x '.*' /Volumes/directory9/ /Volumes/directory10/ | sed 's/^.\{24\}//g' > /Volumes/stuff.txt
diff -r -x '.*' /Volumes/directory11/ /Volumes/directory12/ | sed 's/^.\{24\}//g' > /Volumes/stuff.txt

after="$(date +%s)"
elapsed_seconds="$(expr $after - $before)"
echo Elapsed time for code block: $elapsed_seconds
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When files are different `diff` will be able to figure that out fairly quickly. When they're the same, though, it has to scan the files in full to verify that they are indeed byte-for-byte identical.

If all you care about is differences in file names and don't want to inspect the contents of the files, try something like:

```
diff <(find /Volumes/directory1/ -printf '%P\n') \
     <(find /Volumes/directory2/ -printf '%P\n')
```

This assumes you have GNU find with the `-printf` action. If you don't, use some subshell magic per Gordon's comment:

```
diff <(cd /Volumes/directory1; find .) \
     <(cd /Volumes/directory2; find .)
```

Comment: If you don't have GNU find, this should work: `diff <(cd /Volumes/directory1; find .) <(cd /Volumes/directory2; find .)`

Comment: @gordon thank you, this is definitely on the right track (as i am on mac os x and do not have GNU find). can you explain whats going on? it looks like you are finding the diff of the output of a find . in both directories?

Comment: thanks, that makes sense as it always finds the difference right off the bat and then takes the rest of the 80-odd minutes to say nothing.

Comment: @rick: Both John's and my version use `find` to generate a list of filenames in the directory (and its subdirectories), then compare the lists.  Since it's only fetching and comparing the files' names, not their contents, it'll run very fast (but not detect if the two directories have files with matching names but different contents).

Comment: awesome trick! both work for me, but the `find .` is easier to type heh. In fact I've done a generalization passing `$1` and `$2` into a script named `mydiff.sh` to have it handy ;) `diff <(cd $1; find .) <(cd $2; find .)`

Comment: Find in two different directories may produce results in different orders. The command in the answer detected that nearly everything was different. In my case, I believe it was caused by one of the directories being in a CIFS mounted directory. Adding a sort to each find command helped: `diff <(find dir1 -printf '%P\n'|sort) <(find dir2 -printf '%P\n'|sort)`